# How to properly filter this image using OpenCV in Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

I have a computer vision project where I need to recognise digits on some totems which contain direction signages, an example image is here :
[image: example_image]

So I tried many methods such as taking laplacian,

```
img = cv2.imread(imgpath)
img = cv2.resize(img,(600,600))
imaj = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(11,11),0)
imaj = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
laplas = cv2.Laplacian(imaj,cv2.CV_16SC1,ksize=5,scale=5,delta=1)
```

After applying this, I get a pretty good distinguish between background and the digits but since the output becomes 16SC1, I can not take the contours in the image. I tried thresholding this, but still can not get anything clear out of it.

That's what i get after thresholding from range(5000,8000) and converting it to uint8,[image: after laplacian and threshold]

In the end, I try to take contours from it with this code here :

```
def drawcntMap(filteredimg):
    """
    Draws bounding boxes on the contour map for each image
    """
    contour = cv2.findContours(filteredimg, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[1]
    digitCnts = []
    # draw bounding boxes for contour areas, then filter them approximately on 
    # digit size and append filtered ones to a list
    for c in contour:
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        if w >= 7 and h >= 10 and w <=50 and h <=70:
            digitCnts.append(c)
    #create another contour map with filtered contour areas
    cnt2 = cv2.drawContours(img.copy(), digitCnts, -1, (0,0,255),2)
    #draw bounding boxes again on the filtered contour map.
    for c in digitCnts:
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(cnt2, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0,255,0), 2)
    return cnt2,digitCnts
```

result would be :

[image: result]

How can I improve my solutions for this task and get all the digits? Besides laplacian filter, I tried darkening the image by lowering contrast and extracting white color regions (It did kinda good but still couldn't get all the digits), I tried gaussian blur and canny edge but at some places where the totem and the background are in the same pixel value contours merged.

Comment: I believe you need to isolate the ROI of the number then throw it into OCR such as Pytesseract. One approach is to use color thresholding with `cv2.inRange()` and to isolate white on the image. Then you can perform morphological operations to remove the small noise. Finally, dilate the image to connect the numbers into a single contour. From here you can find contours and isolate the ROI using numpy slicing and throw it into OCR

Comment: I can only use opencv for my project, I tried filtering white and performing morphological operations like you said but it did not come out any good